# Plot Lat, Long, and Temperature as a Contour Plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, contour

I am really at a stand still -- thinking it would be easy.

I have 3 arrays - Latitude, Longitude, and Temperature,

and at each data point or location I want to plot the temperature

as a contour plot.

So at `(45,123)` the temperature `= 73`.

Sample of Values:

```
 Latitude = [45 45 67 34 31 54 60 63 61];

 Longitude = [123 121 117 114 132 119 122 135 134];

 Temp = [73 75 75 73 67 72 82 78 80];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better late than never! In case someone is looking for a working code should know the `contour` function is a little bit tricky, you have to use a matrix to show the contour plot. So:

```
n = length(Latitude);
[X, Y] = meshgrid(linspace(min(Latitude), max(Latitude), n), linspace(min(Longitude), max(Longitude), n));
Z = griddata(Latitude, Longitude, Temp, X, Y);
contour(X, Y, Z);
```

If you prefer a filled plot use:

```
contourf(X, Y, Z);
```

And if you wish to draw your plot over a `worldmap`:

```
contourfm(X, Y, Z);
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Thanks so munch @Sdghasemi.  Thought after 6 years my question would never be answered.

Answer (score 1):

What's the difficulty?  Just use the contour function.
http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/contour.html

```
contour(Latitude,Longitude,Temp)
```